# WPF add event in definition of object

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I wanted to ask, if it's possible to add event into definition of object. I know how to add event to object when you define it 'separately', not 'nested'  like this. But I'd like to use this kind of syntax.
Thank you.

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel()
{
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Children =
    {
       new Button
       {
          Content = "Click Here",

           // !!! NEED ADD CLICK EVENT HERE !!!
       }
     }
};
```

Comment: "I'd like to use this kind of syntax." - very simple - you can't. it is not supported

Comment: You should do it after the constructor is completed.  Not in the constructor.